# Multicore: LPC43xx series :Clock for Cortex M0

Tags: c, arm, clock, multicore, cortex-m

I am new to the world of Multi-core. I am working with the LPC43xx  series. I am trying to blink LED with my secondary core Cortex M0. I would like to know the difference between these Reference clock and Processor Clock in cortex M0. Does reference clock refer to the clock of master core  CM4 ? Does processor clock refer to the clocks of CM4? I am bit not clear with many clocks present in CM4 and nothing in CM0 ? Which clock should I initialize for blinking (delay) ? My code as follows :

```
#include "lpc43xx_gpio.h"
#include "lpc43xx_scu.h"
#include "lpc43xx_cgu.h"
#include "LPC43xx.h"
#include "ipc_int.h"
#include "lpc43xx_libcfg_default.h"

#define LED1_BIT            7 //LEDUSB
#define LED1_PORT           7

/************************** PRIVATE VARIABLES *************************/
static uint32_t msec;


/************************** PRIVATE FUNCTIONS *************************/
void SysTick_Handler (void) ;

void SysTick_Handler (void)     // SysTick Interrupt Handler @ 1000Hz
{
    if(msec)msec--;
}


int c_entry (void) {   



    CGU_Init();

    scu_pinmux(0xE ,7 , MD_PDN, FUNC4);     // P8.1 : USB0_IND1 LED

    GPIO_SetDir(LED1_PORT,(1<<LED1_BIT), 1);

    SysTick_Config(CGU_GetPCLKFrequency(CGU_PERIPHERAL_M4CORE)/1000);

    GPIO_ClearValue(LED1_PORT,(1<<LED1_BIT));



    while (1)
    {                                               // Loop forever
        msec = 1000;
        while(msec);
        GPIO_ClearValue(LED1_PORT,(1<<LED1_BIT));
        msec = 1000;
        while(msec);
        GPIO_SetValue(LED1_PORT,(1<<LED1_BIT));
    }
}

 int main(void)

{


    return c_entry();

}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Normally a reference clock is a (relatively if not much more accurate crystal based external clock) which you use in front of a PLL to create a (typically faster) clock.  Ethernet certainly does this, our multi ghz processors do.  The references in the documentation appear to imply the same.  Do you have an external crystal based something off chip as a reference, at what frequency and what frequency is your processor running at?

Comment: were you able to blink the led without interrupts first?

Comment: I did not try with interrupts ,as I am new to multicore , I  am trying to learn how to handle the cores individually, then I will learn about their communication. To work with CM0,it was written just to reset the CM0 in CM4, so I was trying it.

Comment: sorry, events, you have a systick handler so you are trying to use the "event" or "exception" rather than just checking the status register and not enabling interrupts.

Comment: about systick : For applications that do not require an OS, the SysTick can be used for time keeping, time measurement, or as an interrupt source for tasks that need to be executed regularly. As,there is  RTOS, I am trying to use the systick for the timing purpose like delay.

Comment: Just trying to help you walk before you run and get your led blinking, did you walk before you ran is the question?  now you say you are on an rtos.

Comment: oops sorry, I wanted to say that the LPC43xx series has no OS - baremetal or RTOS !

Answer (score 0):

According to page 170 of the [LPC43xx User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10503.pdf), the Cortex-M0 core clock is supplied by BASE_PERIPH_CLK while the Cortex-M4 is clocked by BASE_M4_CLK. You can set the source of those clocks to any of the (many, many) permissible sources as described in the same chapter.

The "reference clock" you refer to may be the reference clock for the Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I will try this and let you know the results

Comment: Hello, but the BASE_PERIPH_CLK is used for M0SUB system. The cortex - M0SUB is present only in LPC437x sereis. But I am not using that. So I think this wil not be suitable.

Comment: It should be present in all members of the LPC43xx family, since it's the clock for the Cortex-M0. Unless you're using some other LPC part without an M0 core?

Comment: On second reading it seems you're right, the other LPC43xx have M0APP instead, which is clocked by BASE_M4_CLK so it's the same clock as the Cortex-M4 core.

Comment: @Kael see page 212 of the user manual, the Cortex M0 clock is derived from the BASE_M4_CLK.